# ERP solution on .net 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, deployment, hosting

I just joined a new company , which is going to start working on an ERP solution. For this solution they are using .Net 3.5 instead of .net 4.0.Because they think that .Net 4.0 is still not stable and it may has server hosting issues.

I have searched on .net and found no results related to .net 4.0 issues .Also I recently did myself a small website on .net 4.0 and found no issues related to performance , API stability or hosting.

Can anyone here give me any valid guidance to choose .Net 3.5 over 4.0 or vice versa?

Comment: I would point out that .NET 4.0 was released almost a year ago. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions)

By the time your company ships the ERP solution, it will be well over a year old, perhaps more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many companies are conservative, and feel that the newest technology should be allowed to mature before being used, regardless of whether or not there are any proven problems.  If that's their position, there's not much you can do about it.

The only thing you can say is that .NET has proven itself to be a very stable framework, even in .0 releases.  Historically, there have not been many stability or security issues with it.  But as they say, past performance is no inidcator of future results.

Answer (score 1):

There are none. .Net 4 just adds new functionality on the existing framework.

**Update**

There are one valid reason: they want to support [Mono](http://www.mono-project.org) (to be able to run on other platforms than windows)

Comment: They do not want to support mono.